# API for Speakerdeck.com

Tags: api, rest, github

I've been searching if there is an API for Speakerdeck.com.
Unfortunately, Google and Bing thinks I am searching for API related slides in that site.
I couldn't find info at Speakerdeck.com or Github.com, Is there an API?
If so, where I can find the documentation?

Any help is highly appreciated.